# $\text{col }A \stackrel{?}{=} \ker B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these two matrices:

[image]

I've found the basis for $\text{col }A = \pmatrix{1 \\2 \\1 \\2},\pmatrix{2 \\3 \\2 \\3}.$

And the basis for $\ker B = \pmatrix{-2 \\-1\\1\\0},\pmatrix{-1\\1\\0\\1}$.
I add these together in one $4 \times 4$ matrix: 
$$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & -2 & -1 \\2 & 3 & -1 & 1 \\1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\2 & 3 & 0 & 1 }$$

I row reduce and get the $4 \times 4$ matrix identity matrix.

My question is whether or not $\text{col }A = \ker B$.
According to the answer book this is the case. And it's here I get confused. I thought this could only be true if the two sets of bases were linearly dependent, but the identity matrix clearly says otherwise?

Is the answer book wrong or am I? Thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfortunately not familiar with that language. If you have an answer to my problem anyway, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tak skal du have. Fik præcis dette spørgsmål til eksamen, og tror det var det rigtige, da jeg ikke var den eneste der svarede dette.

Comment: Godt at høre! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your calculations and they were correct.

With regard to the dispute, I'd say your book is wrong: The two sets of vectors do not span the same space, so *clearly* the spaces that they span are not the same (in fact, they are orthogonal!), i.e. $\text{col } A \not = \ker B$.

Must be a mistake in the book.